# Strange error while trying to make install Gtkaml (and libvala-0.16) in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vala

I have downloaded and tried to install [Gtkaml](https://code.google.com/p/gtkaml/) but I am having troubles.

I followed their instructions to install it, but it still fails.

I downloaded it into my downloads folder, then ran Terminal:

`cd ~/Downloads`
`ls`
`cd gtkaml-0.5.94`
`./configure`

But then it failed at `./configure`, I can't remember what it was, but it was missing something so I then ran:

`sudo apt-get build-dep gtkaml`, then I re-ran `./configure` and it succeeded. So then I proceeded to `sudo make`, but then it said,

> jase@Jase-PC:~/Downloads/gtkaml-0.5.94$ sudo make make  all-recursive
>   make[1](https://code.google.com/p/gtkaml/): Entering directory `/home/jase/Downloads/gtkaml-0.5.94'
>   Making all in libgtkaml make[2]: Entering directory`
>   /home/jase/Downloads/gtkaml-0.5.94/libgtkaml' /usr/bin/valac -C  -H
>   gtkaml.h --library gtkaml --vapidir . --pkg config --pkg glib-2.0
>   --pkg libvala-0.16 --pkg libxml-2.0 --pkg gio-2.0 gtkamlcodecontext.vala gtkamlmarkupparser.vala gtkonparser.vala
>   gtkamlmarkupscanner.vala gtkamlmarkupresolver.vala
>   gtkamlcodeparserprovider.vala ast/gtkamlmarkupattribute.vala
>   ast/gtkamlmarkupcomplexattribute.vala gtkamlmarkupclass.vala
>   ast/gtkamlmarkuptag.vala ast/gtkamlmarkuproot.vala
>   ast/gtkamlmarkupchildtag.vala ast/gtkamlmarkupunresolvedtag.vala
>   ast/gtkamlmarkupmember.vala ast/gtkamlmarkuptemp.vala
>   ast/gtkamlmarkupreference.vala gtkamlmarkupnamespace.vala
>   gtkamlmarkuphint.vala gtkamlmarkuphintsstore.vala
>   gtkamlpropertyspec.vala workarounds/gtkamldatatypeparent.vala
>   workarounds/gtkamlcallable.vala workarounds/gtkamlvalaparser.vala
>   workarounds/gtkamlnamespacevisitor.vala error: Package `libvala-0.16'
>   not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection
>   GIR directories Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) make[2]:
>   *** [libgtkaml.stamp] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/jase/Downloads/gtkaml-0.5.94/libgtkaml' make[1](https://code.google.com/p/gtkaml/): ***
>   [all-recursive] Error 1 make[1](https://code.google.com/p/gtkaml/): Leaving directory
>   `/home/jase/Downloads/gtkaml-0.5.94' make: *** [all] Error 2

So then I ran `sudo apt-get install libvala-0.16` to install `libvala-0.16`. It then said,

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Note, selecting 'libvala-0.16-dev' for regex
>   'libvala-0.16' Note, selecting 'libvala-0.16-0' for regex
>   'libvala-0.16' Note, selecting 'libvala-0.16-0-dbg' for regex
>   'libvala-0.16' libvala-0.16-0 is already the newest version.
>   libvala-0.16-0-dbg is already the newest version. libvala-0.16-dev is
>   already the newest version. The following packages were automatically
>   installed and are no longer required:   libqt5declarative5 par2
>   python-support Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them. 0 to upgrade,
>   0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

So I re-ran `sudo make`. But same error as the original make error.

How do I make/make install this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been unable to `make` from source obtained from the Google code website. But I have been able to install it from the Software Center.

I have written and compiled a sample application:

```
<Window xmlns:g="http://gtkaml.org/0.4" xmlns="Gtk" g:name="GTKamlSample"
    type="{WindowType.TOPLEVEL}" title="Window"
    position="{WindowPosition.CENTER}" default-width="300" default-height="150"
    destroy="Gtk.main_quit">
    <Button label="Click me." clicked='{target.label="Thank you.";}' />

    <![CDATA[
        static int main (string[] args)
        {
            Gtk.init(ref args);

            var window = new GTKamlSample();
            window.show_all();
            Gtk.main();

            return 0;
        }
    ]]>
</Window>
```

Which works. So your best bet is to use Software Center if you run into troubles installing it from source.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the problem

```
sudo apt-get install libvala-0.16-dev
```

What you need is a libvala development package.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that and it says it's already installed and gives me the same error. It says: "error: Package `libvala-0.16' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
make[2]: *** [libgtkaml.stamp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/jase/Downloads/gtkaml-0.5.94/libgtkaml'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jase/Downloads/gtkaml-0.5.94'
make: *** [all] Error 2
"

Comment: yep, but as stated in the question, ./configure succeeds without error. But `make` fails. With the above error.